# Employee monthly report including leaves and working days

Tags: sql

Consider one week report start Dates: from `11/1/2022` to `11/5/2022`

Table : *Timesheet*

| timesheet_id | start_time_server | Login_by | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 11/1/2022 | 16:20:00 AM | jon 101 |
| 1235 | 11/1/2022 | 12:20:100 AM | tom 102 |
| 1236 | 11/2/2022 | 18:40:00 AM | tom 102 |
| 1237 | 11/3/2022 | 18:40:00 AM | tom 102 |

Table : *Leaves*

| timesheet_id | Leave_applied_date | Leave_start_time_server | user_id | user_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 11/1/2022 | 16:20:00 AM ######### | 101 | jon |
| 1234 | 11/1/2022 | 16:20:00 AM ######### | 101 | jon |
| 1234 | 11/1/2022 | 16:20:00 AM ######### | 102 | jon |
| 1234 | 11/1/2022 | 16:20:00 AM ######### | 103 | jon |
| 1237 | 11/3/2022 | 18:40:00 AM ######### | 102 | tom |
| 1237 | 11/3/2022 | 18:40:00 AM ######### | 102 | tom |

final output **DailyWorkReport** :

| user_name | 11/1/2022 | 11/2/2022 | 11/3/2022 | 11/4/2022 | 11/5/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jon | 8 | Leave | Leave | Leave | Leave |
| tom | 8 | 8 | 8 | Leave | Leave |

Please help how i can achieve this final Dailyworkreprot.

Comment: please clarify the data you provide by using table, including the expected result

Comment: the `id` and `name` values within the first table should really be adjacent nested within a single column ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan       please note Table:Timesheet has 4 columns i.e. timesheet_id ,start_time_server. Login_by(user_name) and user_id.     
timesheet_id   start_time_server Login_by user_id 
1234   11/1/2022  16:20:00 AM   jon          101 
1235   11/1/2022  12:20:100 AM  tom  102 
1236   11/2/2022  18:40:00 AM    tom        102 
1237   11/3/2022  18:40:00 AM   tom 102

Comment: @Mahes , Please note for expected results  we can show 0 for leave .

Comment: @Mahes  please help to resolve this .

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Please help to resolve this .